# openVPN tunnel works for SSH but web sites hosted on the vpn server does not work

Tags: vpn, browser, openvpn, webserver, website

I have a website hosted on a server, let's say 192.168.1.109. I have set up OpenVPN to allow access to this server when I'm not on the local network. SSH works but when I try to hit a port with a webserver serving the UI on a web browser, it doesn't work, something like 192.168.1.109:8080.

Without the tunnel connected, this will work if I'm within the local network.

I'm using tunnnelblick for my vpn client.

VPN and webserver is on the same machine.

Comment: If you telnet to the webserver on appropriate port when the tunnel is up, do you get a connection (ie is the port open?) If so, this could be an MTU issue. MTU issues are not uncommon with VPNs.

Comment: All ports should be open and ssh works so at least I know port 22 is open. Is there a way to check the other ports?